# Многомерный список

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests

Что я не так делаю? выводит только последнюю строку

```
res = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast",params={'id': city_id, 'units': 'metric','lang': 'ru', 'APPID': appid})
    data = res.json()
    forecastlist=[]

    for i in data['list']:
        forecast=i['dt_txt'],'{0:+3.0f}'.format(i['main']['temp']),i['main']['pressure'],i['main']['humidity'],i['wind']['speed']
        forecastlist = np.array(forecast)
        weather = forecastlist.reshape(-1, 5)


    print(weather)
```

А мне нужно добиться такого результата:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста сделать, вопрос жизни и смерти(((((
Потом этот список будет нарезаться по датам без времени

Comment: forecastlist = np.array(forecast) -> forecastlist.append( np.array(forecast)) ? А еще лучше в цикле forecastlist.append(forecast), затем после цикла перевести forecastlists в np.array.

Comment: Вот такой вывод: [array(['2020-05-13 15:00:00', '+18', '1006', '65', '4'], dtype='<U19'), array(['2020-05-13 18:00:00', '+15', '1008', '78', '3.91'], dtype='<U19'), array(['2020-05-13 21:00:00', '+13', '1009', '89', '2.82'], dtype='<U19'),

Comment: не совсем понимаю,другой цикл создать? простите за возможно глупые вопросы

Comment: Ну а вы чего хотели? вы получили список массивов numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
res = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast",params={'id': city_id, 'units': 'metric','lang': 'ru', 'APPID': appid})
data = res.json()
forecastlist=[]

for i in data['list']:
    forecast=i['dt_txt'],'{0:+3.0f}'.format(i['main']['temp']),i['main']['pressure'],i['main']['humidity'],i['wind']['speed']
    forecastlist.append(forecast)


weather = np.array(forecastlist).reshape(-1, 5)
```

я не могу воспроизвести ваш пример, потому что у меня нет api-key и идентификатора города

Comment: получилось,огромное спасибо за помощь!